# I can not get this do while loop to NOT function using else if. if this the correct way?

Tags: c#

i am close to finishing my course on C# basics, but like the textbook says, error handling is the hardest.

i can't this if else construction to work with this do while loop, after a day of false having read that it should be written with a try catch.. this have driven me crazy already :(.

the rest of the software works. (calculation)

if anybody can explain it to me thanks in advance.

code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    int number = 0;// ik maak twee int variabelen om mee te rekenen
    int multiply = 1;

    number = int.Parse(txbGetal.Text);

    if (number = 2)
    {

        do
        {

            txbTafel.Text = txbTafel.Text + "\r\n" + number * multiply++ + "\r\n";
        }

        while (multiply <= 10);
        return;
    }

    if (number <= 12)
    {
        do
        {
            txbTafel.Text = txbTafel.Text + "\r\n" + number * multiply++ + "\r\n";
        }

        while (multiply <= 10);
        return;
    }
    else
        MessageBox.Show("...");
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you getting an error? the wrong result?

Comment: _if (number = 2)_ is not a comparison. It is an assignement and you should have an error message telling you that the compiler cannot convert type int to bool. Use _if (number == 2)_

Comment: If you want to see.an error condition (in particular, an exception), type something other than an `int` into your `txbGetal` textbox. Look up `int.TryParse`

Comment: the problem is if i enter 1 or >12, it still shows the table of. I added tryParse, and that took care of any input other then int. Anybody on getting the messagebox if 1 or >12 is entered. ( i already added the extra = mentioned before)

Answer (score -1):

i figured it out myself.. i was working with a old version of what i had made, with several small errors, so i made a new one and figured out how to make this work.

code:

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

```
        int number = 0;
        int multiply = 1;
        number = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);


        if (number >12)

        {

            MessageBox.Show("....");
        }

        else


        do
            {

                textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + "\r\n" + number * multiply++ + "\r\n";
            }

            while (multiply <= 10);
            

        

    }
}
```

}

thanks everybody for your effort..

greetings,

stefan.